# How i select a subscriber to send the newletter in magento

Tags: magento, newsletter, subscriber

I am using magento-1.7.2 and have made templates for newsletter.
But i not able to select the subscribers and newsletter date to send it.

How i can send a newsletter, can any one describe it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got solution to send newsletters in magento, Magento not gives the option to send newsletters.

You can do it by following these steps:

A. Create a action "send" in your controller and get all newsletters from "newsletter_queue" table to send all subscribers(from "newsletter_subscriber" table).
Use Mail function of Magento to send mail.

B. Write cron-job to call above action.[How set cron job](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job)

C.  set cron-job for each 10 min.